# Determine if a .pdf file has any form elements of any type

Tags: php, pdf, zend-pdf

I need to determine if a given .pdf file has any form element in it (could be text input, check box, list, etc...)

I don't need to know what kind they are or how many there are, I just need to know that there is more than 1 field of any type in the file.

I already have PHP (5.3), Zend_Pdf and tcpdf at my disposal.

It does not appear that Zend_Pdf offers anything to simply list or count form fields.

My option seems to be to convert the pdf to html and parse the result for form fields  or convert the pdf to a text file and parse it.

Are there any better solutions out there?

Answer (score 0):

The `Zend_Pdf` class has the information you need, but it's not accessible or available through a function. You would need to add a public function to look through `$this->_trailer->Root->AcroForm->Fields->items` (for the Zend_Pdf object itself) and look for the frequencies of unique values of `->FT->value` (the field type) for the fields stored in it.